# Parenting bones and armature: " cant find solution for one or more bones"

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, parent

I am doing the rigging part and to parent the bones and the armature when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> I get a message bone heating waiting:

> cant find solution for one or more bones.

Comment: Please upload your .blend file here to be able to help you http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 1):

The automatic weights option works only if the mesh is single and manifold (no spare parts, no holes, no doubles, no intersecting areas, no loose geometry).
Search in this site with keywords "bone heating" for more informations, or do a manual weighting if you can't fix the problem.